# Fluid simulations on spherical coordinate grid: How to handle $\theta=0$ axis?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, software, algorithms

I am working on a fluid simulation code written in spherical coords.  Whoever wrote the original didn't do a great job with the boundary conditions at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ axes.  My task is to "do it right".  This is a time-explicit finite difference code with an algorithm sort of related to the old standard Lax-Wendroff.  I have some ideas, but don't want to re-invent the wheel.  Can anyone point me to a paper or a report on how people have done this?  Believe me, I have done my own internet search on this and am surprised at how hard it has been to find anything.

Comment: What is the boundary condition?

Comment: @gabe    Right now, the grid goes to just a few degrees short of the pole.  And then the values on the grid points in that last circle are calculated by linear interpolation from the next to last circle.  Clearly unsatisfactory.

Comment: @bob.sacamento What problem are you solving?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  This is a compressible fluid code that I am working on.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Can you describe the problem in more detail? Boundary conditions are part of the problem.